# Copy value from one file and paste it on an existing file which a certain pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to write a simple script to copy a value line #1 from a file then copy this value to an existing file after certain pattern or word example "firstvalue ="

```
sourcefile.txt
1234567890
```

```
targetfile.txt
firstvalue =
```

I can do it with grep but I can only replace the whole file.

```
#!bin/bash
awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

Desired output

```
targetfile.txt
firstvalue = 1234567890
```

Just trying to learn basic awk and copy value from one file onto another, I have tried with AWK I can print and get value but I cannot pass them on the target file after certain string patterns.

Comment: Please format your code with code blocks. and add input and desired output.

Comment: I would use `/bin/ed` for that

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable,

The `sourcefile.txt` and its content.

```
1234567890
```

The `targetfile.txt` and its content.

```
firstvalue =
```

---

The script using `ed`

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s targetfile.txt <<-EOF
  /firstvalue =/s/\$/ /
  kx
  0r sourcefile.txt
  .m'x
  -1;+j
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

If both files has one line, then William Pursell is right, you can just use `paste` and an alternative is `pr`, something like:

```
pr -tms' ' target.txt source.txt
```

---

Or with `ed` and `pr`, something like: (*in_place* edit of `target.txt`)

```
printf '%s\n' '0r !pr -tms" " target.txt source.txt' 'w target.txt' ,p Q | ed -s /dev/null
```

---

Although it can be done in *one_line* with `ed` also, something like:

```
printf '%s\n' '$r source.txt' '1s/$/ /' '.;+j' ,p Q | ed -s target.txt
```

---

Output

```
firstvalue = 1234567890
```

---

If the files in question has more lines.

- The `sourcefile.txt` and its content. ( The first line is the target according to the OP)

```
1234567890
0987654321
3465879012
...
```

---

- The `targetfile.txt` and its content.

```
...
another value =
firstvalue =
something value =
...
```

---

The script with `ed`

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s targetfile.txt <<-EOF
  1ky
  /firstvalue =/s/\$/ /
  kx
  0r sourcefile.txt
  1m'x
  -1;+j
   1;'y-d
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

Output

```
...
another value =
firstvalue = 1234567890
something value =
...
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in_place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.
- See GNU [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
- See POSIX [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk` and `sed`:

`sourcefile.txt` content:

```
1234567890
```

`targetfile.txt` content:

```
firstvalue =
```

Solution:

```
awk -v variable=$(sed '1!d' sourcefile.txt) '{$2=$2" "variable}1' targetfile.txt
```

This will append the second column of `targetfile.txt` with below output:

```
firstvalue = 1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { OFS = substr((FS = "^firstvalue =") " ", 2)
>
> NR == FNR ? (__=$-_)<_ : NF<=!_ || $NF = __' <(printf '%s' '1234567890') 
>                                            <(printf '%s' 'firstvalue =')
> ```

```
firstvalue = 1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need awk or sed or grep for this.  Just use paste:

```
$ cat targetfile.txt 
firstvalue =
$ cat sourcefile.txt 
1234567890
$ paste -d\  targetfile.txt sourcefile.txt > tmp && mv tmp targetfile.txt
$ cat targetfile.txt 
firstvalue = 1234567890
```